# How can I fetch the data via select and subselect or join statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have these data in the postgres DB:

```
id type  repair status 
1   0     open
1   1     repaired
2   0     open
3   0     open
3   1     repaired
3   1     repaired
4   1     repaired
5   0     open
5   1     open
5   1     repaired
5   0     open
5   1     repaired
6   1     repaired
6   1     open
```

I want to fetch status of all id's (id can be some thing like book etc.). The type column means: 0 is not bookable, 1: is bookable.

Example id:5
i want to get only the type not bookable, because there are dataset repair status open and the thing is not bookable.

Example id:6
I want to get only the type bookable, because in spite of repair status open the thing is bookable.

can i do it via one select query (ths query can contain subqueries or/and joins)?

I expect this result:

```
id type  repair status 
1   0 open
2   0 open
3   0 open
4   1 repaired
5   0 open
6   1 open
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per `id` in Postgres, the best solution is `distinct on`.  The only question is your `order by` clause.

Your rules are rather hard to decipher.  My best guess is:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
order by id, bookable desc, (status = 'open')::int desc;
```

In standard SQL, you would change the `order by` to:

```
order by id, bookable desc,
         (case when status = 'open' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: I still have a question. Can I do this query via standard sql? because if I use hibernate then the postgres specifics will not work :/